# Can I use Polymer elements / WebComponents with TinyMCE?

Tags: javascript, tinymce, polymer, web-component

I'm trying to build a custom TinyMCE editor for teaching content which will allow certain blocks to be wrapped as an 'activity'. There will be multiple activities in a block of content so they'll have IDs as primary keys etc.

My challenge is implementing a plugin which permits this -- ideally, I would use shortcodes but they're very error prone. I was looking into using custom HTML tags which would be rendered through Polymer -- can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I worked it out fully after about 4 hours.

The TinyMCE editor needs to be initialized with support for custom elements as so:

```
{
...
    extended_valid_elements : 'module-activity',
    custom_elements : 'module-activity',
    init_instance_callback: function(editor) {
        registerCustomWebComponents(tinymce.activeEditor.dom.doc);
    },
...
}
```

Where `registerCustomWebComponents` looks like:

```
function registerCustomWebComponents(doc) {
  doc.registerElement('module-activity', ModuleActivityHTMLElement);  
}
```

I ended up defining the custom HTML element and then defining a React component rather than building the HTMl as a string.

```
class ModuleActivity extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.openActivityEdit = this.openActivityEdit.bind(this);
  }

  openActivityEdit() {

  }

  render() {
    return <div>
      <h3>Module Activity</h3>
      <button onClick={this.openActivityEdit}>Edit</button>
      <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.props.contentHtml }} />
    </div>;
  }
}


class ModuleActivityHTMLElement extends HTMLElement {
  attachedCallback() {
    let self = this;
    var mountPoint = document.createElement('div');
    this.createShadowRoot().appendChild(mountPoint);
    ReactDOM.render(<ModuleActivity contentHtml={self.innerHTML}/>, mountPoint);
  }
}
```

Comment: could please put example in codepen.io or somewhere else?

Answer (score 3):

The solution provided by @liamzebedee being a bit outdated, here is a solution *au goût du jour* with an ES6 module and a standard Web component.

The major difference from the code above is the injection in the TinyMCE `<iframe/>` of the script defining the Web component. Otherwise, the accepted tag stays inert.

First, here is the piece of code related to the TinyMCE initialization:

```js
const name = 'custom-element';
const attribute = 'view-mode';
const insertTag = '<custom-element view-mode="editing"></custom-element>';
const definitionFile = './custom-element.js';

tinymce.PluginManager.add(name, function(editor, url) {
    editor.ui.registry.addButton(name, {
        text: name,
        onAction: () => editor.insertContent(insertTag)
    });
});

tinymce.init({
    // ...

    custom_elements: name, // just the custom Web element names
    extended_valid_elements: `${name}[${attribute}]`, // names+attributes

    init_instance_callback: function(editor) {
        const edDoc = editor.getDoc();
        const scriptTag = edDoc.createElement('script');
        scriptTag.src = definitionFile;
        scriptTag.type = 'module';
        // Injection of the definition file in the <iframe/> document
        edDoc.querySelector('head').appendChild(scriptTag);
    }
});
```

The corresponding (minimal) Web component is defined as:

```js
export class SimpleNumber extends HTMLElement {

    constructor() {
        super();

        // Add a simple <input/> field in the ShadowRoot
        this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'}).innerHTML = `
            <style>
                :host { display:inline-block; }
                input { border: 1px solid blue; font-size: 12pt; text-align: right; }
            </style>
            <input type="number" min="0" max="10" value="0" />
        `;

        // Provide some feedback when the  <input/> field value changes
        this.shadowRoot.querySelector('input').addEventListener('change', (event) => {
            const field = event.target;
            field.style.backgroundColor = field.value === '3' ? 'lightgreen' : 'orange';
        });
    }
}

if (window.customElements && !window.customElements.get('simple-number')){
    window.customElements.define('simple-number', SimpleNumber);
}
```

Note that I cannot provide a running example on *codepen.io* (for example) because I cannot have a separated JS file for the custom element definition (the file that need to be injected into the `<iframe/>`)…

Answer (score 0):

The answer here is don't use tinymce in polymer, tinymce is heavily reliant on the document root and shadow dom will break it.

But like everything in life, all is not lost...

Use an object in your polymer template, have the object load tinymce and solve the document root issue. You can then access tinymce from the object once loaded in such a way as this.

Create a HTML file to load tinymce

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://cloud.tinymce.com/stable/tinymce.min.js"></script>

    <style>
        html { height: 96%; }
        body { height: 96%; }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <textarea>Loading...</textarea>
    <script>
        var ta = document.querySelector('textarea');
        ta.tinymce = tinymce;
        var editorChangeHandler;
        tinymce.init({ selector: 'textarea', height: document.body.scrollHeight - 100, setup: function (editor) {
            editor.on('Paste Change input Undo Redo', function () {
                if (editorChangeHandler) { clearTimeout(editorChangeHandler); }
                editorChangeHandler = setTimeout(function () {
                    ta.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('save'));
                }, 2000);
            });
        } });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Now you just need to add an object to the template of your component, use the data attribute of the object to load the html.

Once it is loaded, you can access it, query the object dom and grab the textarea, add event listener for save custom event and also pre set the contents, adjust height anything. I have only tested this same domain, so be aware this might break cross domain but you want to serve alongside the other components anyway.

Add your object to your component template

```
<object id="editor" type="text/html" data="/src/lib/tinymce/tinymce.html"></object>
```

And some way to pre-load, grab stuff, set height and catch save

```
ready() {
    super.ready();

    // wait five seconds before capturing input
    var interval = setInterval(() => {
        if (!this.$.editor.contentDocument.body) return;
        let ta = this.$.editor.contentDocument.body.querySelector('textarea');
        if (!ta || !ta.tinymce || !ta.tinymce.activeEditor) return;

        // clear interval now loaded
        window.clearInterval(interval);

        setTimeout(() => {
            // resize on window change
            window.addEventListener('resize', this._updateEditorSize.bind(this));

            // pre load
            ta.tinymce.activeEditor.setContent(this.element.value);

            // catch updates every few seconds, this will then have a 4 second debounce on save too naturally
            ta.addEventListener('save', (ev) => {
                this.set('element.value', ta.tinymce.activeEditor.getContent({ format: 'raw' }));
            });
        }, 250);
    }, 250);
}
```

This is a working scenario for polymer 3 and tinymce, loads quick, auto resizes and catches save event from object and I do not have to change tinymce from it's default setup. You can also use this method for other means to get around shadow dom with some embedded applications.