# Define Web Component inside IFrame

Tags: javascript, iframe, web-component

To enhance my tinyMCE Editor, I would like to add some web components and use them inside the editor. Something similar has been done by [others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38733649/can-i-use-polymer-elements-webcomponents-with-tinymce), but with older versions of the editor and javascript, which is not valid anymore.

I am aware, that I have to register the tag inside the editor configuration so this works already and my tag makes it to the dom. The problem is, that given components are not defined inside the editors IFrame.

I was not able to add them to the iframes window, the error message doesn't really tell why though. For Testing purposes, I also added the web component to the regular window, where it works flawlessly.

The IFrame:

```
<iframe srcdoc="<demo-cmp></demo-cmp>" onload="registerComponent(this)"></iframe>
<demo-cmp></demo-cmp>
```

The Web Component Definition:

```
class DemoComponent extends HTMLElement {
  connectedCallback() {
    alert(window.location.href);
  }
}

window.customElements.define('demo-cmp', DemoComponent);

function registerComponent(iframe) {
  // Exception thrown here
  iframe.contentWindow.customElements.define('demo-cmp', DemoComponent);
}
```

The Error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Custom element constructor returned a wrong element

The Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/ynpks9m3/10/

Comment: Have you figured out how to do this?  I'm trying to do the same thing in Angular.

Comment: @Optiq are you also struggeling with the tinymce? We decided for injecting a script tag into the editors dom elements. But finally are using the editor without the iframe so it's inline and not a problem anymore.

Comment: no I'm building an Angular project.  I created a new CSS tool for responsive design and am using a resizable iframe in the documentation site I'm making so users can see how things scale.  The tool I built works off of the window size and an iframe is the only element that provides a separate DOM instance.  I can embed angular components programmatically but its not allowed in firefox so I wanted to see if I could do it with the srcdoc property and a web component.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem when defining web components in IFrame. If can, switch TinyMCE to inline mode to solve it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).